# If $p^n$ divides $q^n$ does $p$ divide $q$?

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

Im looking to proof the folowing:

> $p^n|q^n \implies p|q$

It seems clear to me that it is correct. When i follow the induction: for $n=1$ that's just obviously true but im stuck with the induction step:
$(p^n|q^n \implies p|q) \implies (p^{n+1}|q^{n+1} \implies p|q)$

Is there any other way to simply (dis)prove this?
Thanks for any helpful answers.

Comment: Think about the prime factorization of $p$ and $q.$

Comment: Yes, that's what i originally looked at but I'm looking for a mathematical proof.

Comment: You can give a rigorous mathematical proof using this unique factorization property of integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different proof that doesn't directly use induction can go like this. Consider $ (p,q)=1$, that is $p, q$ are co-prime , if not just cancel the common factors. Now since $ p^n|q^n$, we have $ \frac{q^n}{p^n}=k $ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. 
Consider the polynomial $x^n-k$. Clearly, $\frac{q}{p}$ is a root of $x^n-k$. The Rational Root Theorem  implies only possible rational roots of $x^n-k$ would  of the form $\frac{m}{r}$ where $m|k$ and $r|1$ for some $m,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ , it is follows that $\frac{q}{p}$ is an integer. Thus $p|q$.

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed as follows, without using induction. If $p \not| q,$ then $q/p$ is a noninteger rational number. Then any positive integer power of it $(q/p)^n = q^n/p^n$ must also be noninteger, because all noninteger $n$th roots of an integer are irrational (see [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/12/20/roots-of-integers/) for proofs of this). Therefore, for any $n,$ $p \not| q => p^n\not|q^n, $ and [hence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) the contra-positive $p^n|q^n => p|q$ follows.

Comment: I think you have the meaning of the symbol $|$ mixed up.  If $p\mid q$ (*and $p\neq 0$*) then $\frac{q}{p}$ is an integer, not the other way around.  The phrase $p\mid q$ reads "p *divides* q" which is the same as "q is *divisible by* p." You need to swap most of the occurrences of $p$ in your post with $q$'s and vice versa.

Comment: Good point, fixed it now

Comment: Wait, assuming we have a rational number that is not an integer e.g. 3/4 then you say that any of its nth power is irrational? That's incorrect, because (3/4)^2=9/16 which is just another rational number.

Comment: Edit: I overlooked your statement,...You have just proved the statement for $n \notin N$ But not for $n \in N$. E.g take $p=4$ and $q=3$. Using your proof this would go: $4∤3$ thus $\frac{3}{4}$ is noniteger rational number. Then raising this to the third power we obtain: $\frac{3^3}{4^3}=\frac{27}{64}$ which is still rational, isn't it?

Comment: Assuming we have a rational number $\frac{q}{p}$ that is not an integer, then for any positive integer $n$, the $n$th power $\frac{q^n}{p^n}$ is rational but is not an integer. For example, $\frac{27}{64}$ is rational and noninteger.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong again, sorry, i didn't realise we were proving the "reversed" implication. It's clear for me now, thanks